# The update information is outdated UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, update-manager

I'm seeing a red triangle with exclamation mark in the right corner.

I ran `sudo apt-get update` and found these lines in the output-

```
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-en_IN                            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-en                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               

Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages   
Err http://download.videolan.org  Sources                                      
  403  Forbidden [IP: 88.191.250.2 80]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages   
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages     

Err http://download.videolan.org  Packages                         
  403  Forbidden [IP: 88.191.250.2 80]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                

Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages                

Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               

Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                 

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages                

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                 

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages                

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                 

Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                

Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_IN             
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
Err http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 88.191.250.2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 88.191.250.2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/games/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

So all your main archives are updating fine and you will continue to get updates from them.

The only problems I can see above it that `download.videolan.org` and `archive.getdeb.net` appear to be unavailable. Perhaps they have changed how they format their repos. Perhaps they have withdrawn them completely. If you want to know for certain, check with the provider of the repo.

If you can't find out any information, removing these broken repositories will silence the warnings.

But again, this isn't interfering with Ubuntu-provided packages and updates.

Comment: Just to note as well, unofficial repos such as getdeb and videolan are unsupported by Ubuntu. These kinds of repos are used at your own discretion. That's not to say people won't help you, it's just not recommend since it makes it harder to diagnose problems because you're not using the official packages.